# Can I read the browser url using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-webdriver

I am using python2.7 with `beautiful Soup4 and Selenium webdriver`. Now in my webautomation script i will open the link or URL and get into the home page. Now I need to click onto some `anchor Labels` to navigate through other pages.I did till now. now when i will be going to a new page, I need to get the new `URL` from the browser as I need to pass it `Beautiful Soup4` for webpage scraping. So now my concern is how to get such URLs dynamic way?

Please advice if any!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get current URL in Selenium Webdriver 2 Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985339/how-do-i-get-current-url-in-selenium-webdriver-2-python)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get `current_url` attribute on the driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print(browser.current_url)
```