# How do I get current URL in Selenium Webdriver 2 Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the current url after a series of navigations in Selenium. I know there's a command called getLocation for ruby, but I can't find the syntax for Python.

Comment: Selenium doc explains it all :https://www.selenium.dev/docs/site/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#get-current-url

Comment: @anandharshan this link Not working. please update it

Answer (score 445, accepted):

Use current_url element for Python 2:

```
print browser.current_url
```

For Python 3 and later versions of selenium:

```
print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: or, also known as `driver.current_url`

Comment: suppose, there is a chain of page p1->p2->p3 where p2 on the basis of credentials in p1 is redirecting to either p1 or p3. How to get the url just after clicking which I am not able to understand. selenium doesnot stop at that page and is directly giving me the url of p3. how to go for this?

Comment: @proprius https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592602/how-can-i-get-a-intermediate-url-from-a-redirect-chain-from-selenium-using-pytho

Comment: more importantly, where is this documented on https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ ?

Comment: @RobertJohnstone: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=current_url#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url

Answer (score 98):

According to this [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url) (a place full of goodies:)):

```
driver.current_url
```

or, see official documentation:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#get-current-url

Answer (score 7):

Selenium2Library has get_location():

```
import Selenium2Library
s = Selenium2Library.Selenium2Library()
url = s.get_location()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it would be to inspect the url bar in chrome to find the id of the element, have your WebDriver click that element, and then send the keys you use to copy and paste using the keys common function from selenium, and then printing it out or storing it as a variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the current URL via the `driver`:

```py
driver.current_url
driver.execute_script("return document.URL;")
driver.execute_script("return document.location.href;")
driver.execute_script("return window.location.href;")
```

(Note that there are differences between the various JS variables for this, as specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388084/7058266)

In some cases, you might not want the full URL, but the `origin` instead:

```py
driver.execute_script("return window.location.origin;")
```

For example, on stackoverflow pages (such as this one), the origin is `https://stackoverflow.com`. (Useful for when you don't want the full URL.)

There are also popular Python frameworks, such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), with built-in methods for returning the URL, (or the origin):

```py
self.get_current_url()    # SeleniumBase only
self.get_origin()         # SeleniumBase only
```