# How can I get a intermediate URL from a redirect chain from Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, selenium-webdriver, event-handling

I'm using Selenium with Python API and Firefox to do some automatic stuff, and here's my problem:

1. Click a link on original page, let's say on page *a.com*
2. I'm redirected to *b.com/some/path?arg=value*
3. And immediately I'm redirected again to the final address *c.com*

So is there a way to get the intermediate redirect URL *b.com/some/path?arg=value* with Selenium Python API? I tried `driver.current_url` but when the browser is on *b.com*, seems the browser is still under loading and the result returned only if the final address *c.com* is loaded.

Another question is that is there a way to add some event handlers to Selenium for like URL-change? Phantomjs has the capacity but I'm not sure for Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer my own question.

If the redirect chain is very long, consider to try the methods @alecxe and @Krishnan provided. But in this specific case, I've found a much easier workaround:

> When the page finally landed c.com, use
>   `driver.execute_script('return window.document.referrer')` to get the
>   intermediate URL

Answer (score 5):

You can get redirects from `performance` logs. According to [docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log) and [github answer](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1844) here is what I've done in C#, should be possible to port in Python:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
var cap = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
var perfLogPrefs = new ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences();
perfLogPrefs.AddTracingCategories(new string[] { "devtools.network" });
options.PerformanceLoggingPreferences = perfLogPrefs;
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.EnableProfiling, true, true);
options.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
var url = "https://some-website-that-will-redirect.com/";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance"); //all your logs with redirects will be here
```

Looping through `logs`, if `message.params.redirectResponse.url` is equal to original URL then `message.params.request.url` will contain redirect URL

Answer (score 2):

Proxy Servers such as BrowserMob proxy can be setup into your Selenium test and then have your web traffic routed via the the Proxy server. The traffic information is all captured as HAR files.You can try getting this information by plugging in a proxy server such as [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)

AFAIK The only listening hook in mechanism that Selenium provides is the [EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) wherein you can plugin your own event listening by extending [AbstractWebDriverEventListener](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/AbstractWebDriverEventListener.html) via the [register](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html#register-org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener-) method in EventFiringWebDriver. But the EventFiringWebDriver has limitations. It cannot eavesdrop into events that arise out of Actions class. There's an alternative to that as well. Sometime back I created a blog post that talks about it. Maybe you can refer that as well. Here's the [link](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/eavesdropping-into-webdriver/)

I don't know if there is similar to this in Python (since I have never worked with the Selenium Python bindings )

Comment: Thanks for your helpful info and I'll have a look at it. But for my case I've found a workaround to get the right URL :-)

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to get the intermediate redirect URL b.com/some/path?arg=value with Selenium Python API?

I would use an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) with a small poll interval. The idea would be to wait for the *staleness of the body element*  on the initial page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, poll_frequency=0.05)
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(body))
print(driver.current_url)
```

You might also need to *decrease the page load timeout*:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(0.5)
```

> Another question is that is there a way to add some event handlers to Selenium for like URL-change?

This is exactly what these Explicit Waits are about. There are relevant `title_is`, `title_contains` expected conditions and it's easy to write your [custom one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848) (for example, to wait for some substring in the current URL).

Comment: And I tried your method with wait condition EC.title_contains but it doesn't work. The reason I guess is the browser is still under loading when it's on address b.com, which makes the wait condition is hanging forever.

Comment: @shizhz okay, can you provide a way for us to reproduce the problem (perhaps, showing what code you have and the desired result)? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I've found a workaround for my case: when the page finally landed c.com, I use driver.execute_script('return window.document.referrer') to get the previous URL.