# How to get the current web page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i use selenium get web page and i send kenword get a new page. but how can i get the new web page ,and search the information that i need

---

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

test_url = 'https://www.baidu.com/'

browser.get(test_url)


in_put = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="kw"]')
name = 'python'

in_put.send_keys(name.decode())
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="su"]')
button.click()


page = browser.page_source

with open('baidu.html','wb') as f:
    f.write(page)
```

Forgive me for not using markdown. My question: i want to get the web page after search keyword, but i write browser.page_source , it is the  Baidu's home page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get current URL in Selenium Webdriver 2 Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985339/how-do-i-get-current-url-in-selenium-webdriver-2-python)

Comment: thank you ,it Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

To get the current page URL using selenium on python use

```
browser.current_url
```

instead of

```
browser.page_source
```

Here is the changed code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
in_put = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="kw"]').send_keys('python')
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="su"]').click()
page = browser.current_url
print(page)
with open('baidu.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(page)
```

Output:

```
https://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=0&rsv_idx=1&tn=baidu&wd=python&rsv_pq=c42791f700000914&rsv_t=d395wla6YQdEj168mrNDyE2%2FUMDzBUE3I%2FcwHbURsI%2FZ5TUaGFq1o83M2Qc&rqlang=cn&rsv_enter=0&rsv_sug3=6&inputT=610&rsv_sug4=611
```