# How to get the URL "about:blank" from empty tab using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to check that an opened tab is empty and switch to another one.

I tried the `get_current_url()` method, but it does not work.

```
def check_is_tab_empty(self, link):
    self.click(link)
    self.focus_active_tab()
    tab = self.get_current_url()
```

This line `tab = self.get_current_url()` - does not work if a tab is empty, like `about:blank`.

Comment: tab = self.get_current_url() returns an error or something else?

Comment: It returns TimeoutException

Comment: instead of self.get_current_url() try self.current_url or self.get_location()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985339/how-do-i-get-current-url-in-selenium-webdriver-2-python

Comment: Thanks, but self.current_url also doesn't work.
And how the self.get_location() can work if it uses the self.driver.current_url

Answer (score 1):

You have switch to the new tab to get the url of the new tab.Lets take an example here.You have open a blank page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.yahoo.com')
windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
driver.execute_script('''window.open('{}');'''.format("about:blank"))
windows_after = driver.window_handles
new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: Actually in the `self.focus_active_tab()` I switch to a new tab using `self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])`

Comment: There is no problem to get a URL of any tab.
There is a problem to get a URL in case of **empty tab** with "about:blank".

Comment: This example I am getting the url “about:blank”

Comment: If you could share an example they would help

Comment: You open a new empty tab. 
While I should handle a case when after clicking on a link an empty tab is opened instead of a site.

Comment: By the way the code is opening a Tab not window.did u try the code?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to handle this case by the `try ... except` statement:

```
        try:
            tab = self.get_current_url()
        except TimeoutException:
            ...
            self.click(link)
            self.focus_active_tab()
            tab = self.get_current_url()
```

Now it works for me as for the second time a link (not empty one) is opened.

But if someone knows a better solution, please, share.